# How to check if the tag of a button is the same of the text of a label when clicked, the text of the label is from a array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, if-statement, windows-forms-designer

[image: -Picture what this is about-]

So I have an array that contains names of counties. The label's text (see picture '2') has the text of the value of the array. The button (see picture '1') has the tag "Drenthe", which is the same value as the array.

My question is: how do i check if the tag of the button which i click is the same as the label text. Can this be done with an if statement? If so how?

If the right button is clicked the score should get ++, and if not the score should get --.

Comment: `if(label.Tag == button.Text){/*do something*/}`

Comment: You mean:
if(button.Tag == label.Text)
{
    score++;
}

Comment: I am getting this alert: Warning: *Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'*

Comment: Cast tag to string: `(string)button.Tag`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use the if statement ,
you can use the following code to check the condition

```
if(label.Text==button1.Text)
{
 /// do somethings 
}
```

Comment: I meant the tag of the button, for every button tag/county there is a name in the array. I want to have it the way so it gets score++; when i click on the right button which matches the label text/county name.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your question

Comment: Actually what u want?